# Woocommerce show related products in order emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a way to add a section to my order emails in Woocommerce to show related products. I have already customized the php templates for my emails, but cannot seem to find the right code snippet to call the related products function.

I tried the solution in the thread without succes:
[How to add related products or cross sells to order emails in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723931/how-to-add-related-products-or-cross-sells-to-order-emails-in-woocommerce)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hook **woocommerce_email_after_order_table** to show text after order table.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'add_order_email_instructions', 10, 2 );

  function add_order_email_instructions( $order, $sent_to_admin ) {
   if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {
     echo 'Custom HTml OR Custom Text';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hritik,

However, I am not looking to just add some custom HTLM or text, but the output from the "related products function", meaning product pictures, price, etc.